# error retrieving user object in context in apollo server v4 for token authorisation

Tags: postgresql, jwt, apollo-server

I am trying to learn JWT using my demo chat app built using apollo server **V4**, I am facing issue with authorisation in jwt.I feel the problem is in the context function.
i am not able to retrieve the user object in context function
and does not show any output when did console.log
this is my resolver code below

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'; 
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
const pubsub = new PubSub();

export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUser: async (_, {id}, { pool }) => {
     
      try {
        
        const user = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [id]);
        return user.rows[0];
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch user');
      }
    },
    getMessages: async (_, { userid }, { pool }) => {
      try {
        const messages = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE userid = $1', [userid]);
        return messages.rows;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch messages');
      }
    },
    getChatMessages: async (_, { chatsessionid }, { pool }) => {
      try {
        const messages = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatsessionid = $1', [chatsessionid]);
        return messages.rows;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch chat messages');
      }
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    registerUser: async (_, { username, password },{ pool }) => {
      try {
        const client = await pool.connect();

        // Check if the username already exists
        const existingUser = await client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1', [username]);
        if (existingUser.rows.length > 0) {
          client.release();
          throw new Error('Username already exists');
        }

        // Generate a unique ID for the user
        const id = uuidv4();

        // Hash the password
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        // Insert the new user into the database
        const query = 'INSERT INTO users (id, username, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING *';
        const values = [id, username, hashedPassword];
        const result = await client.query(query, values);
        const newUser = result.rows[0];

        client.release();
        return newUser;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to register user');
      }
    },
    login: async (_, { username, password },{ pool }) => {
      try {
        const client = await pool.connect();

        // Check if the username exists
        const query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1';
        const values = [username];
        const result = await client.query(query, values);
        const user = result.rows[0];

        if (!user) {
          client.release();
          throw new Error('Invalid username or password');
        }

        // Check if the password matches
        const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isPasswordValid) {
          client.release();
          throw new Error('Invalid username or password');
        }

        // Generate JWT token
        const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id  }, "somereallylongsecret",{ expiresIn: '30d' });
        console.log(user.id);

        client.release();
        return {
          token,
          user,
        };
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to login');
      }
    },
    
    createChatSession: async (_, { useraid, userbid }, { pool }) => {
      try {
        const chatsessionid = uuidv4();
        const query = `
          INSERT INTO chatsessions (id, useraid, userbid)
          VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
          RETURNING *
        `;
        const values = [chatsessionid, useraid, userbid];
        const result = await pool.query(query, values);

        const createdChatSession = result.rows[0];
        // Publish the created chat session to the subscription channel
        pubsub.publish('NEW_CHAT_SESSION', { newChatSession: createdChatSession });

        return createdChatSession;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to create chat session');
      }
    },
    sendMessage: async (_, { userid, chatsessionid, content }, { pool, user }) => {
      console.log('Authenticated User:', user);

      if (!user) {
        throw new Error('Authentication required to send a message');
      }

      try {
        // Generate a unique ID for the message
        const messageid = uuidv4();

        // Insert the new message into the database
        const newMessage = await pool.query(
          'INSERT INTO messages (id, content, userid, chatsessionid) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *',
          [messageid, content, userid, chatsessionid]
        );

        const createdMessage = newMessage.rows[0];

        // Publish the created message to the subscription channel
        pubsub.publish('NEW_MESSAGE', { newMessage: createdMessage });

        return createdMessage;
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to send message');
      }
    },
  },
  Subscription: {
    newMessage: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
        () => pubsub.asyncIterator('NEW_MESSAGE'),
        (payload, variables) => {
          return payload.newMessage.chatsessionid === variables.chatsessionid;
        }
      ),
      resolve: (payload) => {
        return payload.newMessage;
      },
    },
    newChatSession: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
        () => pubsub.asyncIterator('NEW_CHAT_SESSION'),
        (payload, variables) => {
          const { useraid, userbid } = variables;
          const { useraid: sessionUser1Id, userbid: sessionUser2Id } = payload.newChatSession;
          return (
            (useraid === sessionUser1Id && userbid === sessionUser2Id) ||
            (useraid === sessionUser2Id && userbid === sessionUser1Id)
          );
        }
      ),
      resolve: (payload) => {
        return payload.newChatSession;
      },
    },
  },
};
```

this my index.js file below

```
import { expressMiddleware } from '@apollo/server/express4';
import { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } from '@apollo/server/plugin/drainHttpServer';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from '@graphql-tools/schema';
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import { useServer } from 'graphql-ws/lib/use/ws';
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { typeDefs } from './schema.js';
import { resolvers } from './resolvers.js';

import pkg from 'pg';
const { Pool } = pkg;

// import {  getUserId  } from './decodedToken';


const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mychatapp',
  password: '*******',
  port: 5432, // Change the port number if necessary
});


  


// Create the schema, which will be used separately by ApolloServer and
// the WebSocket server.
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

// Create an Express app and HTTP server; we will attach both the WebSocket
// server and the ApolloServer to this HTTP server.
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

// Create our WebSocket server using the HTTP server we just set up.
const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
  server: httpServer,
  path: '/graphql',
});
// Save the returned server's info so we can shutdown this server later
const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

const getUser = token => {
  try {
    if (token) {
      return jwt.verify(token, "somereallylongsecret")
    }
    return null
  } catch (error) {
    return null
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  plugins: [
    // Proper shutdown for the HTTP server.
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),

    // Proper shutdown for the WebSocket server.
    {
      async serverWillStart() {
        return {
          async drainServer() {
            await serverCleanup.dispose();
          },
        };
      },
    },
  ],
  
//   context: () => ({ pool }), context is now used in expressMiddleware on v4 
  
});
await server.start();
app.use(
  '/graphql',
  cors({

    origin: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',

    credentials: true,

  }),
  bodyParser.json(),
  expressMiddleware(server, {

    // context: async({ req }) => {
    //   const token = req.get('Authorization') || ''
    //   return {pool, user: getUser(token.replace('Bearer', ''))}
    // },
    context: async ({ req }) => {
      const token = req.headers.authorization || '';
      // if (!token) {
      //   return { pool };
      // }

      try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "somereallylongsecret");
        const userId = decoded.userId;

        // Fetch user from the database and include it in the context
        const getUserQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1';
        const getUserValues = [userId];
        const userResult = await pool.query(getUserQuery, getUserValues);
        const user = userResult.rows[0];
        console.log('User Object in Context:', user); // Add this console.log statement

        return {
          pool,
          user,
        };
      } catch (error) {
        return { pool };
      }
    },
  }),
);

await new Promise((resolve) => httpServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000/graphql`);
```

Any suggestions would really be helpful.